# RethinkDB - Search contents of list?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a rethinkDB with a complex JSON key structure that stores data and log files in the form of long text strings.

In each entry, I have something like:

```
{"serial": "fun",
"Time delay": 20,
"MAC address list": [
  "0c:c4:c1:24:24:55",
  "0c:c4:c1:24:24:56",
  "0c:c4:0a:fd:e2:12"
 ]}
```

I need to search all of the (hundreds of thousands of) entries for the presence of a MAC address.  Say I'm searching for "0c:c4:0a:fd:e2:12".  How would I use the RethinkDB HTTP interface (java script based) to do that?

**I'm essentially looking for the equivalent to python's "if X in list1"**.

Comment: What java-based HTTP interface are you talking about? I don't know of any. The ReQL equivalent of `in` is `r.contains`.

Comment: The http interface that defaults to :8080 when you run Rethinkdb.  It's Java-based, so the rethink queries have to be in Java style syntax.

Comment: RethinkDB's built-in web UI is JavaScript-based, not Java.